# OpenGL vertex shader: weird matrix translation

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, vertex-shader

I'm trying to move a triangle based on time using a matrix. But it does some weird stuff:

**What it should do:**
move on the x-axis

**What it does:**
The top point of the triangle is fixed and the other points seem to move around it in a circular movement and scale on the x, z axis (I'm still in 2d so I don't have depth).

My C++ Code:

```
    ...
    GLfloat timeValue = glfwGetTime();
    GLfloat offset = (sin(timeValue  * 4) / 2);

    GLfloat matrix[16] = {
        1, 0, 0, offset,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    };

    GLuint uniform_m_transform = glGetUniformLocation(shader_program, "m_transform");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_m_transform, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
    ...
```

My vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
 layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
 layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;

 out vec3 ourColor;
 uniform mat4 m_transform;

 void main()
 {
     ourColor = color;
     gl_Position = m_transform * vec4(position, 1.0);
 }
```

I don't know what I did wrong, according to the tutorial the matrix attribute I've set to offset should change the x-translation.

Do you know what's my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are providing a row-major matrix, so you need to specify the transpose:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniform_m_transform, 1, GL_TRUE, matrix);
```

Reference: [glUniform](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml), check the *transpose* parameter.

Comment: @yxyx136: It boils down in which order the elements of the matrix are read. row order means, that the base vectors that make a matrix (remember a matrix is a vector of vectors) are indexed first by row, then by column). OpenGL natively however assumes, that the elements in the buffer making a matrix are ordered column first; so when writing it as a C array it looks transposed (flipped along the diagonal). While this may seem cumbersome at first it has certain benefits when it comes to computer graphics, since often you need to address the column vectors of a matrix, e.g. for making billboards.